# What is ungrammatical about "that's them"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

I was reading 3rd short story in Agatha Christie's "Poirot Investigates" when I stumbled on following sentence:

> "That's them," I declared in an ungrammatical whisper.

What is so ungrammatical about *that's them*? What would be considered grammatically correct instead?

Comment: Grammatically, it should've been *that's **they***, instead? What do you think?

Comment: A. *them* 2. Informal. (used instead of the pronoun *they* in the predicate after the verb to be ): *It's them, across the street. It isn't them.* http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/them  B. "Fowler says:  me is technically wrong in *It wasn't me* etc.; but the phrase being of its very nature colloquial, such a lapse is of no importance". http://alt-usage-english.org/excerpts/fxitsmev.html

Comment: Pullum goes further: **Myth**: Expressions like "It was me" and "She was taller than him" are incorrect; the correct forms are "It was I" and "She was taller than he." 

Pullum responds: The forms with nominative pronouns sound ridiculously stuffy today. In present-day English, the copular verb takes accusative pronoun complements and so does "than." My advice would be this: If someone knocks at your door, and you say "Who's there?" and what you hear in response is "It is I," don't let them in. It's no one you want to know. ( http://www.universityofcalifornia.edu/news/article/4225 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"That's" = "That is". To preserve number, you could say instead "*Those are (those're)* them". You might only do this in a formal context (in which case you would also not use the contraction).

Comment: And this is precisely why grammar is trivial: idiomatic English always trumps grammatical English. If such a declarative is necessary in formal written English -- novels aren't in that category, thank goodness -- then it's necessary to recast the sentence as something like "_Those are the killers_". But in dialog, whatever people say is what is written, and the reading's all the better for that. "I declared in an **ungrammatical** whisper" is merely Christie's successful attempt to say "_I said_" in an unusual and more interesting way than "_I whispered_".

Comment: @BillFranke: Slight correction -- grammar **isn't** trivial; it's bullshit grammar that's trivial. It is simply an insane idea that the **correct** version should be some monstrosity like _Those are they_ instead of the perfectly grammatical and normal _That's them._ There is way too much nonsense circulating about English grammar.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yes, you're right. I agree that my statement is over the top hyperbolic & insufficiently qualified. It misrepresents the value of studying grammar (which I've always loved but now find useful only for parsing sentences & deciding how to arrange them; I no longer teach grammar or much beyond writing). It's also insulting (unintentional but carelessly unconsidered before I uttered it) to professional linguists, for which I apologize to all the linguists here. I'll be more circumspect in future about casting such a wide net & being thoughtlessly critical & condescending.

Comment: No offense; what irks me is that so many people think of grammar as this system for putting other people down instead of as the fascinating web of phenomena that it is. All the social static about "correctness" makes people deaf to what's actually going on. Oh, well, humans will be human, I guess.

Comment: -1 Unless we know the context, there's no way to tell the *that* even refers to *them*. "That's not me (I)" is perfectly grammatical as far as the *that* is concerned. How can we say we need *those*, unless we know it referes to *them*? It could be like the existential *it*, even.

Comment: @Kris If you had intended your comment constructively, you would have attached it to the question. Then you would simply have been wrong. The context is known: the OP cited the source, so we have the entire original work to refer to. But criticizing my answer for a (supposed) fault of the question is also unconstructive. This seems like post-hoc rationalization of a grudge vote.

Comment: @MετάEd First things first: I never see the poster, only the post, when voting. :) So, relax.

Comment: The question only contains a reference. You have taken the trouble of reading (more likely, had already read long ago) the source.

Comment: @Kris We can disagree on that, but this still leaves my second point: if the quotation lacks context, fault the question—not an answer.

Comment: The question is 'What is so ungrammatical?' and the answer would be 'Nothing.' It's that simple. You did take pains to find what *could* be wrong, a possibility. Every sentence can be *incorrect* (not grammatically - perhaps semantically) in a certain context. We need to focus on the OP's basic question, after all, right?

Comment: The question is what grammatical error does Agatha Christie's character refer to. You are so concerned with whether it is *actually* an error that you have missed Christie's point and the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

'Them' is an object pronoun. 'They' is the corresponding subject pronoun.

In this instance, the people in question are the subject of the sentence, hence 'they'.

Whilst 'those are they' would seem stuffy and too formal, one could always get around it with the much simpler (and grammatically correct) "There they are."